# Modify gradients of a hidden layer and backpropagate modified gradients to find gradients of remaining layers

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, gradient, backpropagation, gradienttape

Consider a neural network with 2 hidden layers. I want to calculate gradients of parameters of 2nd hidden layer wrt loss, modify it and then use the modified gradients to backpropagate and find gradients of 1st hidden layer.
I am currently doing it as following:

```
with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape1:
    # Calculate forward pass
    pred = model(X_data)
    # Calculate loss
    loss = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_data, pred)
#calculate gradients of 2nd hidden layer    
model_gradients_second_layer = tape1.gradient(loss,model.trainable_variables[2:])

#modify model_gradients_later_layer say multiply by 2
model_gradients_second_layer_modified = 2*model_gradients_second_layer 

# calculate gradients of 1st hidden layer
model_gradients_first_layer = tape1.gradient(model.trainable_variables[2],model.trainable_variables[0:2],model_gradients_second_layer_modified [0])    

model_gradients_all_layers = model_gradients_first_layer + model_gradients_second_layer_modified 
optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(model_gradients_all_layers , model.trainable_variables))
```

But model_gradients_first_layer is coming out as None.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is an expected behavior of TF.

In the command line `model_gradients_first_layer = tape1.gradient(model.trainable_variables[2],model.trainable_variables[0:2],model_gradients_second_layer_modified[0])` you are asking the derivative of weights of your model with respect to some weights in another layer. These parameters are involved in **no computational graph (calculation)**.

I think you want to compute the gradients of the loss with respect the first layer:
`tape1.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables[:2])` or something like that.

My advice here would be to compute all the gradients at once and then post process as you need, since calling `tape1.gradient` is expensive. (You can remove the persistent=True argument also).